# Get facebook app id from config/initializers/devise.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've set my facebook app id in config/initializers/devise.rb and now i'm trying to retrieve it in my controller.

How do I call it back?

```
Devise.setup do |config|
    config.omniauth :facebook, 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXX', :scope => 'email,offline_access,user_likes,user_interests,publish_actions,publish_stream'
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Devise.omniauth_configs[:facebook].strategy.client_id
```

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to [change the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120568/is-it-possible-to-change-the-chosen-answer) :)